# Java Deployment, Config File Changes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, configuration, configuration-files

I have a java project deployed on the server.
Now I want to make some changes in "project/WebContent/WEB-INF/configuration.propertys".

My question is do I need to make changes in my local machine and redeploy or can I just make some changes in server's directory? As I can see the configuration.propertys file in server directory I doubt that I can make direct changes to that file and will it be effect to the deployed project

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: which server are you deploying your application to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup , you dont need to go round the complete cycle again, just update the properties file in server directory installed applications and restart your application.

Comment: Thank You Goel. You ans Really Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a DynamicMBean object to reload the properties file dynamically and  it would not require a server restart. I think this is one of the best production quality solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how this properties file is used. If the configuration data is cached in the internal structures, then you have to initiate reinitialization of these structures in order to make the changes effective.

However, in some containers, you will just trigger automatic re-deployment of the application if you change the resources. But this is totally environment-specific.